# SWT/JFace Column and Line Span in TableViewer

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer, columnspan

I need to span some column and rows in a TableViewer. The image bellow pretty much speaks for itself.

http://postimage.org/image/28l8re8lg/

I was thinking of implementing this by making some line invisible(white) but I don't think you can set individual border options for individual cells. Even if i managed this I would stil have to fix the alignment problem of the text in the spanned columns/rows ("Line Span" and "Column Span" in the picture).

I know about the Nebula Grid component, but I can use 3rd party components only as a last resort.

If anybody has any suggestions please share them:).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you use the third party libraries? I see no point in reinventing the wheel. Also, default tree control doesn't support this (at least on windows) and even if you try to implement it by handling paint events then it may not scale up properly for large data set. Still you want to experience it then try looking at the nebula grid source.

Comment: I can't decide if we can use 3rd party libraries. I'm just doing some research to determine if implementing this manually is realistic or not. I really hope we'll end up using nebula's grid.